# What should an unformatted wall of errors without a question be flagged as?

Tags: support, declined-flags

Recently I raised a low-quality flag for the post *[File descriptor leaked on vgs invocation message while updating grub on machines with lvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849837/file-descriptor-leaked-on-vgs-invocation-message-while-updating-grub-on-machines)*, which got declined with the generic response of *declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*.

Since I don't see any way to salvage the question I assume it is because I should have raised another flag. Before guessing, I wanted to ask: Which flag might be appropriate or did I miss the question in the post?

Comment: Needs Improvement -> Unclear would be a better flag in my opinion.

Comment: That specific one can also be flagged as off-topic, as it's about updating grub. [Seems more on-topic for Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/grub/info).

Comment: @Gino Mempin: Yes, it doesn't appear to be about software development at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't flag it as low quality; there is no such flag; you flagged it as very low quality. It would only be acceptable to flag it if the post needs immediate deletion, but is not spam or abusive.

In this case, you can just flag as unclear ("needs details or clarity") and let the review queue close it pending further edits from the author. No need to immediately delete it.

Comment: Where can I figure out which flags call for immediate deletion and which do not? The description of 'severe formatting problems` could be argued for..

Comment: Unfortunately, the flagging modal is a little messy. The options "a duplicate" and "needs improvement" lead to question closure. Others send it to mod queue, which usually means deletion by mods, account suspension or account deletion. For all other issues, you can use custom flag reason (in need of moderator attention).

Comment: @LinFelix "severe formatting problems" usually means it's not fixable by an edit by any user other than the author. Of course, almost anything can be re-written completely but consider *reasonable* edit. Different people would have different definition for what is reasonable to edit but I think all would agree that the edit needed to make the question you mentioned *not* have formatting problems is trivial. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73849837/revisions

Comment: What is an example of 'needs immediate deletion, but is not spam or abusive?'

Comment: @user16217248 Ahh, what an excellent question. Please let us know once you find an answer. :) Moderators would like to know that as well.

Comment: @Dharman I might have found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966972/can-you-help-ddostoppeddd). If that is not VLQ then I do not know what is.

Comment: @Dharman Would you say [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74045947/i-want-the-almost-future) is a good example of a VLQ question? (I.e. not spam or abusive but nonsensical to the point of being unsalvageable and warranting deletion)

Comment: @user16217248 Yes.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, could I use VLQ for questions that are so low quality that salvaging them would be as much work as writing a new question altogether, but closure flags for questions that are merely incomplete, off-topic, etc?

Comment: @user16217248 Yes, but most of the time one of the close reasons is applicable